# Subtracting one day off Calendar doesn't work

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to build a simple program with java.util.Calendar. When trying to get the weekday before, my output always stays the same. Code and what I tried below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        int date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(date).toUpperCase();
```

This was my code at the start. I have tried subtracting day by one:

```
day = day-1;
```

I have tried adding minus one to both the Day of Month and Day of week field:

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

I think that it has something to do with my SimpleDateFormat, but I am not sure.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.  See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571751/642706) by rzwitserloot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to build a simple program with java.util.Calendar.

That is impossible. Specifically, the 'simple program' part. Nothing that uses Calendar is simple.

The calendar API is horrible; it makes no sense (the first month of the year is... 0, to change values, you have to use int constants, which isn't idiomatic java), and is confused about what it is trying to represent (it's not a calendar, it's a date/time value, or, is it? Is it solarflares time, appointment time, or alarmclock time? It's confused and doesn't know). That's why there is a new API: `java.time`. Java does not remove stuff even if it is obsolete, because that would break old code. So, the fact that Calendar is still around doesn't mean much.

Use `java.time`.

> I think that it has something to do with my SimpleDateFormat, but I am not sure.

It doesn't. But let's forget about this silly API and use java time instead!

```
// note that in calendar, january is 0, and that is insane.
// in localdate, it is 1, which is sane.
// thus, assuming you have `month = month - 1;` someplace in your code...
// remove that.

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
DayOfWeek day = date.getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(day);
```

Wanna go back a day? Okay.

```
DayOfWeek day = date.minusDays(1).getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(day);
```

Comment: The whole `Calendar` API was poorly thought out and should be deprecated and removed.  For extra credit, consider what happens if you have a `Calendar` with a current value of `2020-05-31` and you change it to `2020-06-30` using the individual `Calendar.set(field,value)`.  You will NOT get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is that you aren't invoking the method you think you are.  There is no `SimpleDateFormat#format(int)`.  But `SimpleDateFormat` extends `Format`, which declares `Format#format(Object)`.  Your `int` is boxed to `Integer` and then the relevant code in `Format#format(Object)` is

```
    if (obj instanceof Date)
        return format( (Date)obj, toAppendTo, fieldPosition );
    else if (obj instanceof Number)
        return format( new Date(((Number)obj).longValue()),
                      toAppendTo, fieldPosition );
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot format given Object as a Date");
```

At this point, since the value you passed is boxed to `Integer` which extends `Number`, the *second* branch of the `if-else` is taken and your day-of-week value is converted to a date via the constructor.  The number is interpreted as a millisecond value and when you subtracted 1 you changed the time by 1 millisecond, not 1 day.

All that said, you should NOT be using `Calendar`, use the new date/time API in the `java.time` package.